# How to write code within if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to fetch some data from an API on some conditions.  Below is my code:

```
const readmsg = async (a) => {
        ((a.receiver === me) & (a.is_read === false)) ? 
            let data1 = new FormData()
            data1.append('is_read',true)
            await chatApi.post(`updateMsg/${a.id}/`,data1)
        : 
        null
        
    }
```

But this giving me syntax errors. How can I write this correctly? Even I tried `if` and `else` instead of ternery operator, that does not gives syntax error but throws error.

[image: error]

Comment: In the image it looks like you just forgot the curly braces `{}` for the `if` block.  Which would kind of just make this a typo.  (The code shown in the question is very different from what's showing the error in the image...)

Comment: Try wrapping the code after `?` and before `:` with brackets

Comment: ternary makes no sense when you need to run multiple lines of code.

Comment: The ternary operator can only be used with expressions, not statements inside it. Use an ordinary `if` statement.

Comment: This is definitely not a standard use-case for the ternary operator. if...else is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an ordinary `if` statement.

```
const readmsg = async (a) => {
    if (a.receiver === me && !a.is_read) {
        let data1 = new FormData();
        data1.append('is_read','true');
        return await chatApi.post(`updateMsg/${a.id}/`,data1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Additionally:

- Use `&&` to combine conditions; `&` is bit-wise AND.
- The second argument to `FormData.append()` should be a string or blob, not a boolean. Put `true` in quotes to make it a string.
- Don't use `===` when testing boolean values. Just use the value or `!value`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `===` when testing boolean values. It can make code much easier to follow, as well as making it more explicit that you are testing a boolean instead of just looking for truthiness or falsiness.

Comment: @MarkHanna I guess it's personal style, but IME experts mostly prefer the terser style. Testing against `false` is usually only done when you need to distinguish it from other falsey values (e.g. PHP's `strpos()`

Comment: Yeah that's the only time using `===` to test boolean values is strictly necessary in a functional sense. But as you say, it really comes down to preferred code style. Personally, I find it can make code easier to follow, particular for newer developers.

Comment: @MarkHanna In my opinion, the terse syntax mirrors the way we think and talk. You say "Mark is not home", you don't say "Mark being home is false"

Comment: I think that depends on the person, honestly. Another way to read the two (assuming a variable called `isMarkHome` as an example) would be "Not is Mark home" vs "Is Mark home? No". I know at least one experienced colleague of mine prefers the more verbose form because he finds it reads more naturally.